# Will adding content to my site regularly improve SEO performance?

Tags: seo, google, search-results

Does putting up content on a daily basis have a positive effect on Google rankings? Will my site appear higher in SERPs?

Comment: See also: [Are more pages in one site better for SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22732/are-more-pages-in-one-site-better-for-seo)

Answer (score 3):

Count of articles in a website doesn't have any direct impact on the rankings for target keywords.
In case you want to rank for more keywords, you should create more pages for them but also be aware of [cannibalization](https://www.stonetemple.com/keyword-cannibalization-and-seo-what-you-need-to-know/).
You should try to cover synonyms on the same page.
Having more articles also helps the users in case they are looking for any related articles, they will find them on your own website and they won't need to search for similar topics which may be a relevancy factor helping Google rankings.

Answer (score 2):

Fresh content helps you rank better, so the **answer is yes**. But it is just one of dozens of factors. So while you are at putting up content, pay attention to this: Make sure your **whole site and each of the pages ale well structured**. Each page should be about a specific topic, each paragraph on page should, too, be clearly about a sub-topic. To see if you are doing it right, **check that your headings make sense** - they should define what the pages and separate paragraphs are about. H2 headings should fit well under your H1, just as H3 go into depth within the scope of H2, and so on. Good internal linking helps too.